# How to translate product shopping experience texts?

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I have been trying to find out whether one can translate the content from Shopping experience product pages.

I have found the [relevant documentation for Categories](https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-6-en/first-steps/internationalization#shopping-experience-for-categories) but I see no mention of the corresponding product translations.

It seems that this should be a thing that is translatable in the settings where you select the per-product configs for the blocks

I have tried the following:

1. Assign a layout to a product and set its value to "ENGLISH BANNER" in English [image]
2. Switch to German (the "ENGLISH BANNER" is still there) [image]
3. Replace it with "GERMAN BANNER".
   [image]
4. Switch to English again and check the results.
   [image]

Am I doing something wrong? Is this a bug? The Shopware version is 6.4.10. Is there a non-hacky way to translate the content from per-product for product pages in Shopping experiences?

The shop's default language is English if this is relevant.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. What's SW version?

Comment: The Shopware version I experienced this on was 6.4.10. It was also verified on 6.4.17 and 6.4.18.

BTW Shopware has opened [a ticket](https://issues.shopware.com/issues/NEXT-25296) for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce this in higher Shopware versions (6.4.16.0)

The data is stored at `product_translation` in the `slot_config` field, so it looks like this should be translatable in the long run but obviously it's not yet implemented and/or a bug.

You might want to create a request at https://issues.shopware.com/

As a not-to-hacky workaround you might add your translated data to the product entity itself using a custom field. This custom field can be inserted via twig `{{ customFields.my_test_field }}` in the product and the translation works for such custom fields.

Comment: Thx for the suggestion. It actually turns out that it is an Admin-side problem, because the storefront texts appear correctly, but the Administration texts are just the latest text for a given slot. So while it is an editing nightmare, the feature kind of works.

Comment: At least - Please see if there is an issue on issues.shopware.com yet, otherwise open one please.

Comment: This issue was escalated internally until it reached Shopware. The ticket is already open, you can find it [here](https://issues.shopware.com/issues/NEXT-25296)